# Excel VBA Application.Match between Long Time and Custom format

Tags: vba, date, excel, excel-formula

I can't for the life of me get this to work.

I have a column `r` of time values formatted as "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000 AM/PM" (this format is one of the Custom formats one can choose for a cell).

I also have a cell `c` containing a time value formatted as "*hh:mm:ss" (the first Time format).

I now want to find on which row `i` the `c.Value` is in range `r`. I do this using

```
i = Application.Match(c.Value, r, 1)
```

On this row I get the 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch' and my guess is that it is because the cells in `r` has a Custom format, or because there is no date in `c.Value`.

How can I get this to work? Is there some other way I can get the placement of `c.Value` in the range `r`?

Code:

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1:A10")
Dim c As Range
Set c = Range("B1")

Dim i As Integer
i = Application.Match(c.Value, r, 1) 'ERROR!

End Sub
```

SOLVED:

I didn't know Excel treats dates and times as numbers, so I got it to work when saving `c.Value` as a type `Double` before using it in the function.

Comment: The match will raise an error when the value is **not** found by the match function. You can trap this error if you `Dim i as Variant` (since the `Match` may return a `Long/Integer` or an `Error` type, you need a `Variant` container).

Comment: Yes I know, but I know the time is in there. But I managed to solve it, see edit in OP :)

Comment: Cheers. You can add an "answer" to your own question and mark it as accepted :)

Comment: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days", what the hell is the point of that?!

Comment: Sounds like a question for meta.stackoverflow.com :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

I didn't know Excel treats dates and times as numbers, so I got it to work when saving c.Value as a type Double before using it in the function.